# Grunt watch takes too long to recognise a change

Tags: performance, gruntjs

I am working on some sass project and the grunt file looks like this

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

// Project configuration.
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    sass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                style: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                'public/css/all.css': 'public/css/all.scss'
            }
        },
        dev: {
            files: {
                'public/css/all.css': 'public/css/all.scss'
            }
        }
    },
    concat: {
        js: {
            src: [
                'public/js/foot-*.js'
            ],
            dest: 'public/js/foot.js'
        }
    },
    uglify: {
        uglifyjs: {
            options: {
                mangle: false,
                compress: {
                    global_defs: {
                        "DEBUG": false
                    },
                    dead_code: true
                }
            },
            files: {
                'public/js/foot.js': ['public/js/foot.js']
            }
        }
    },
    po2mo: {
        files: {
            src: 'module/frontend/Application/language/*.po',
            expand: true
        }
    },
    watch: {
        options: {
            debounceDelay: 0,
            spawn: false
        },
        js:{
            files: ['public/js/**/foot-*-*.js', 'public/js/**/foot-1-jquery*.js'],
            tasks: ['concat:js']
        },
        css:{
            files: ['public/css/**/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass:dev']
        }
    },
    concurrent: {
        options: {
            logConcurrentOutput: true
        },
        watch: {
            tasks: ["watch:js","watch:css"]
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch'); // not a default task
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-concurrent');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-po2mo');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['sass:dev','concat:js','po2mo']);
grunt.registerTask('prod', ['sass:dist','concat:js','uglify:uglifyjs', 'po2mo']);
grunt.registerTask('watcher', ['default','concurrent:watch']); // we don't have po2mo watcher yet
```

};

The respective lines are:

```
watch: {
        options: {
            debounceDelay: 0,
            spawn: false
        },
        js:{
            files: ['public/js/**/foot-*-*.js', 'public/js/**/foot-1-jquery*.js'],
            tasks: ['concat:js']
        },
        css:{
            files: ['public/css/**/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['sass:dev']
        }
    },
```

But the grunt watcher takes a lot of time to even identify changes. I shared the whole code first as to see if someone can help me with a quick fix?

I am new to Sass but have been doing less for quite a while. No idea why sass is being so slow. I am quite sure the problem lies in the grunt file.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I also use grunt-contrib-watch with settings similar to this, minus the Options section. Is it seeing changes and taking forever to create a new CSS file? If so, that's because grunt-contrib-sass uses Ruby and is super-slow. If you want fast compiling, switch to a task that uses libsass like grunt-sass.